# How to print attribute(which is list) of a class in python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to print attribute(which is a list of another class) of a class one item in row. The code looks something like this:

```
class A:
     def __init__(self, i):
          self.index = i

     def __str__(self):
          return str(self.index)

     __repr__ = __str__


class B:
     def __init__(self):
          self.b = []

     def load(self):
          for i in range(3):
               a = A(i)
               self.b.append(a)

     def __str__(self):
          # My 1st solution
          return self.b
          # My 2nd solution
          for i in self.b:
               print(i)

     __repr__ = __str__


b = B()
b.load()
print(b)       # TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

Expected output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error? Both `__str__` and `__repr__` should return a string, not a list.

Comment: That comment means (also) don't print inside `__str__` method, just return the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join([str(x) for x in self.b])
```

Which would make each `<class '__main__.A'>` inside `self.b` into a `str` before joining them with `.join`.

---

```
>>> print(b)
0
1
2
```

Comment: You don't need to make a new list, `join` will consume a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) - `return '\n'.join(str(thing) for thing in self.b)`